# Connect godaddy domain with heroku showing SSL error

Tags: heroku

I am trying to connect my godaddy in my heroku app. I have tried all things, I have updated the `CNAME` to `www`, `website.herokuapp.com` and I have also update the `A` records to

@: 75.101.145.87

@: 75.101.163.44

@: 174.129.25.170

I have also updated the naked domain by forwading it.

It is showing OK in heroku ACM status next to the domain but when opening in browser, it's throwing SSL error.

`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

I have tried and followed multiple threads but no luck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks